# Trigger function when IMPORTRANGE() is updated

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, importrange, events

I have a sheet *(sheet-A)* that gets it's information from another sheet *(sheet-B)* using `IMPORTRANGE()`. In *sheet-B* [I have a function that formats cells based on the a value in the row](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/103984/using-setbackgroundrgb-over-setbackgroundcolors). At the moment I run this function on a timer because `IMPORTRANGE()` does not trigger an `OnEdit` or `OnChange` event.

I am wondering if there is some other mechanism to trigger an event on *sheet-B* from *sheet-A* so that I can run the function *on demand*<sup>1</sup> and not every minute. At times I may need to run the function every few seconds, and I'd like to keep the formatting somewhat interactive, other times the sheet may not be in use for weeks and I don't need to run the function every minute.

> <sup>1</sup>: By "on demand" I mean to run my function when the value of a sheet from an external spreadsheet file changes.

In other words, I'm looking to automate the trigger of the function. For example in my case the user does not have access to the UI when viewing sheet-B and they are editing sheet-A from another machine. In my case the only way I have found to make this work is by using the time-based trigger.

I looked at [simple](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) and [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) official documentation some time ago, as I said I'm using a simple time-based trigger that runs every minute right now. I'm sure I also looked at installable triggers as well but unfortunately one of their restrictions is they do not run if a file is opened in read-only (view or comment) mode.

Comment: Have you reviewed the [simple](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) and [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) official documentation?

Comment: I looked at both of these some time ago, as I said I'm using a simple time based trigger that runs every minute right now. I'm sure I also looked at installable triggers as well but unfortunately one of their restrictions is `They do not run if a file is opened in read-only (view or comment) mode.` I know I did not specify this restriction in my question, but I don't know what I don't know.

Comment: No problem. I'm just asking to narrow the scope of the question in order to  help the community including myself to provide a better answer than the one that I already posted. By the way, all the relevant details about the question should be included on the question itself, comments are intended to be temporary.

Answer (score 1):

> NOTE: Answer to [revision 4](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/104025/4)

Google Apps Script on edit events are triggered by user made changes only, they aren't triggered on automatic changes like does that occur to automatic recalculation of import functions and functions like NOW. By the other hand, in order to make a change on an external sheet, you should use an installable trigger.

For further details see [Installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) and search about this both on this site and on Stack Overflow.

---

> NOTE: Answer to [revision 1](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/104025/1)

Besides the use of the run command from the Google Apps Script editor, to run a script on demand you could use a [custom menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus). There are several threads that include examples of uses of custom menus on this site. Here are few examples:

- [Google Sheets Customize View Using Create Custom Menu and Hiding/Showing Specifc Columns](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/82666/google-sheets-customize-view-using-create-custom-menu-and-hiding-showing-specifc)
- [Prevent "invoked too many times per second" error in Google Apps script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/80105/prevent-invoked-too-many-times-per-second-error-in-google-apps-script/80122#80122)

References

- [Overview of Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview)
- [Quickstart: Macros, Menus, and Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/macros)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. However I'm looking to automate the trigger of the function. For example in my case the user does not have access to the UI when viewing sheet-B and they are editing sheet-A from another machine. In my case the only way I have found to make this work is by using the time based trigger.

Comment: The question says "I am wondering if there is some other mechanism to trigger an event on sheet-B from sheet-A so that I can run the function on demand and not every minute". My answer mentions "some other mechanism" to run a script. Is your question about "custom events"?

Comment: I guess I missed the word automate. you have already edited my question so thanks. but yes I am looking to run a function on one sheet based on the state of another sheet.

Comment: Running a function on "on demand" and running a function based on an event of another function are two different things. Please refine your question.

Comment: I sorry, I don't understand, I want to run my function when the value of another sheet changes, isnt that both "on demand" and on an event. the issue is I don't know if there is an event that can satisfy my need for the function to run on demand. I honestly am not sure how I could rephrase the question.

Comment: I don't know if someone else undernstand the same as you by "on demand", but I never see that term on the way that you are using it before. I understand "on demand" as manually triggered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55280/discussion-between-hoss-and-ruben).